# Accesing class methods/variables from another class

Tags: c#, list, class, variables, methods

stupid question really,  I have private variables, which I encapsulated and now I want to access them from another class.

I also have a list in one class and want a lot of classes to access that list (list of objects called fields) (creating a simple farm simulator). 
So how can I access them from another class?

1. I know I can make an instace of a class, but with lists, will that mean that my list won't be the same when I create instances of the class in the classes that I want to access the list in?
2. I don't think I can use Namespace.class.Something since their not static, or can I?
3. Maybe use inheritance for list or is that not going to work?

Please help, realllyyy would appreciate any help!!
*thank you in advance

Comment: Read about [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Comment: ? Do you bother to read my question

Comment: I know of that, but also I got lists, if I create many instances won't they be different, see if you read the question you might see what I'm having problems with

Comment: Do you bother to read any C# book/tutorial, read how to ask here on SO. And in fact as a first post, you could be also a little bit more polite also...

Comment: Use of properties is valid for lists, too. You need use same class instance or make class/property static.

Comment: You see I'm used to coding in a game engine ,and I know your property method, I probably phrased the question wrong, but what I'm having problem with is whether I have the correct idea of what they do, mostly for lists, and thanks miKko .but how would I use same instance for a class?

Comment: Again, make class static or inject the class instance as dependency into classes that needs to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a private member from within another class (except the member is a member of a nested class). So the proposal from Konrad Kokosa to use Properties instead was absolutely fine as they should be used to control access from outside the actual class. Having said this you may either turn the access-modifier for that property to public or derive from that class (however, you have to use protected access for the property then).

```
MyClass {
    public static List<Field> MyList {get;set;}
}

AnotherClass {

    AnotherClass() {
        MyClass.MyList = // whatever
        // or also possible
        MyClass.MyList.Add(/*new Item*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that, I know I can access them like that, and I probably will, but what about lists, if I create many instances of list class won't the lists be different in every instance or am I wrong?

Comment: public static IList<Field> Fields = new List<Field>();

Comment: @KlaudijusMiseckas see my updated code that includes a static property

Comment: So if I use use MyClass instance = new MyClass(); , and instance.mylist will be the same in every class that I create it , because I will be adding and changing the list in different classes. If you get what I mean

Comment: @KlaudijusMiseckas You won´t need an instance of MyClass in this case, I updated my code for this scneario

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I was worried at using static at first, but I don't see why not

Answer (score 0):

Private members cannot be used outside of the class (unless you use reflection, which I would not recommend). If you want the members to be available to outside classes, you have to make them "public". If you want your members to be available to all derived classes only, use "protected".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the same list from all o the other classes, you should declare it as static:

```
private static List<Field> s_fields = new List<Field>();
public static List<Field> Fields { get { return s_fields; } }
```

Comment: Hmm thanks I'll try that, do you think using this is good practise or bad, (using static)

Comment: Not a good practice, generally - but this is a very broad question and depends on your preferences, and on existing frameworks you have